# Why does bash ignore newlines when doing for loop over the contents of a C-style string?

Tags: bash, scripting, for-loop, escaping

Why does the following...

```
c=0; for i in $'1\n2\n3\n4'; do echo iteration $c :$i:; c=$[c+1]; done
```

print out...

```
iteration 0 :1 2 3 4:
```

and not

```
iteration 0 :1:
iteration 1 :2:
iteration 2 :3:
iteration 3 :4:
```

From what I understand, the $'STRING' syntax should allow me to specify a string with escape characters.  Shouldn't "\n" be interpreted as newline so that the for loop echos four times, once for each line?  Instead, it seems as if the newline is interpreted as a space character.

I took unwind's suggestion and tried setting $IFS.  The results were same.

```
IFS=$'\n'; c=0; for i in $'1\n2\n3\n4'; do echo iteration $c :$i:; c=$[c+1]; done; unset IFS;

iteration 0 :1 2 3 4:
```

William Purssel says in a comment that this did not work because IFS was being set to newline... but following did not work.

```
IFS=' '; c=0; for i in '1 2 3 4'; do echo iteration $c :$i:; c=$[c+1]; done; unset IFS;

iteration 0 :1 2 3 4:
```

Using IFS=' ' on newline-separated string resulted in even more mess...

```
IFS=' '; c=0; for i in $'1\n2\n3\n4'; do echo iteration $c :$i:; c=$[c+1]; done; unset IFS;

iteration 0 :1
2
3
4:
```

setting IFS to '\n' rather than $'\n' had the same effect as IFS=' ' ...

```
IFS='\n'; c=0; for i in $'1\n2\n3\n4'; do echo iteration $c :$i:; c=$[c+1]; done; unset IFS;

iteration 0 :1
2
3
4:
```

There's only one iteration, but the newline is visible in the echo for some reason.

What did work is first storing the string in a variable then looping over the contents of the variable (without having to set IFS):

```
c=0; v=$'1\n2\n3\n4'; for i in $v; do echo iteration $c :$i:; c=$[c+1]; done

iteration 0 :1:
iteration 1 :2:
iteration 2 :3:
iteration 3 :4:
```

Which still does not explain why there is this problem.

Is there a pattern here?  Is this the expected behavior of IFS as defined in unwind's link?

unwind's link states... "The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within double quotes for word splitting."

I guess that explains why string literals don't get split for for-loop iteration no matter what escape characters are used.  Only when the literal is assigned to a variable then that variable is expanded to be split for the for-loop does it work.  I guess also with command substitution.

Examples:

Result of command substitution is split

```
c=0; for i in `echo $'1\n2\n3\n4'`; do echo iteration $c :$i:; c=$[c+1]; done

iteration 0 :1:
iteration 1 :2:
iteration 2 :3:
iteration 3 :4:
```

Portion of the string that was expanded is split, rest is not.

```
c=0; v=$'1 \n\t2\t3 4'; for i in $v$'\n5\n6'; do echo iteration $c :$i:; c=$[c+1]; done

iteration 0 :1:
iteration 1 :2:
iteration 2 :3:
iteration 3 :4 5 6:
```

When expansion happen in double quotes, no splitting occurs.

```
c=0; v=$'1\n2\n3 4'; for i in "$v"; do echo iteration $c :$i:; c=$[c+1]; done

iteration 0 :1 2 3 4:
```

Any sequence of SPACE, TAB, NEWLINE is used as delimiter for splitting.

```
c=0; v=$'1 2\t3 \t\n4'; for i in $v; do echo iteration $c :$i:; c=$[c+1]; done

iteration 0 :1:
iteration 1 :2:
iteration 2 :3:
iteration 3 :4:
```

I will accept unwind's answer as his link yields the answer to my question.

No clue as to why behavior of echo within for-loop changes with value of IFS.

EDIT: extended to clarify.

Comment: Also try adding a second print in the loop, so you can see how many iterations are made. E.g. "do echo $f ; echo foo ; done".

Comment: @unwind: good suggestion. Moreover, I would also use something like `echo :$f:` to see exactly what $f contains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your `$IFS` setting to change how bash splits text into words.

<sup>Editor's note:

This answer was accepted, because it provides a link to information that ultimately explains the underlying issues.

Note, however, that the OP's problem can *not* be solved simply by changing `$IFS`, because `$IFS` doesn't apply to *quoted strings*.</sup>

Comment: I've tried the following and it failed.  I'll edited my question to reflect this.

    IFS=$'\n'; for i in $'1\n2\n3\n4'; do echo $i; done; unset IFS;

Comment: The problem is that IFS contains newline.  Try IFS=' '

Comment: it puzzles me as to why IFS=' ' works when the string is $'1\n2\n3\n4' and not when it is '1 2 3 4'

Comment: AAAAAHHHH!!!  IFS=' ' does NOT work on $'1\n2\n3\n4'.  It somehow causes \n to become visible in the echo.  See revised question for details.

Comment: I accepted your answer because the link to specification of IFS contained the answer I sought.

Comment: @emraptor: Glad it helped, although I confess I didn't quite realize the answer would be that complicated. That might be because I didn't know about the $'' construct.

Answer (score 9):

Bash doesn't do word expansion on quoted strings in this context. For example:

```
$ for i in "a b c d"; do echo $i; done
a b c d

$ for i in a b c d; do echo $i; done
a
b
c
d

$ var="a b c d"; for i in "$var"; do echo $i; done
a b c d

$ var="a b c d"; for i in $var; do echo $i; done
a
b
c
d
```

In a comment, you stated "IFS='\n' also works. What doesn't work is IFS=$'\n'. I'm very very confused right now."

In `IFS='\n'`, you're setting the separators (plural) to the two characters backslash and "n". So if you do this (inserting an "X" in the middle of a "\n") you see what happens. It's treating the "\n" sequences literally in spite of the fact you have them in `$''`:

```
$ IFS='\n'; for i in $'a\Xnb\nc\n'; do echo $i; done; rrifs
a X b
c
```

**Edit 2** (in response to the comment):

It sees `'\n'` as two characters (not newline) and `$'a\Xnb\nc\n'` as a literal string of 10 characters (no newlines) then `echo` outputs the string and interprets the "\n" sequence as a newline (since the string is "marked" for interpretation), but since it's quoted it's seen as one string rather than words delimited by `$IFS`.

Try these for further comparison:

```
$ c=0; for i in "a\nb\nc\n"; do echo -e "iteration $c :$i:"; c=$[c+1]; done
iteration 0 :a
b
c
:

$ c=0; for i in "a\nb\nc\n"; do echo "iteration $c :$i:"; c=$[c+1]; done
iteration 0 :a\nb\nc\n:

$ c=0; for i in a\\nb\\nc\\n; do echo -e "iteration $c :$i:"; c=$[c+1]; done
iteration 0 :a
b
c
:

$ c=0; for i in a\\nb\\nc\\n; do echo "iteration $c :$i:"; c=$[c+1]; done
iteration 0 :a\nb\nc\n:
```

Setting IFS has no effect on the above.

This works (note that `$var` is unquoted in the `for` statement):

```
$ var=$'a\nb\nc\n'
$ saveIFS="$IFS"   # it's important to save and restore $IFS
$ IFS=$'\n'        # set $IFS to a newline using $'\n' (not '\n')
$ c=0; for i in $var; do echo -e "iteration $c :$i:"; c=$[c+1]; done
iteration 0 :a:
iteration 1 :b:
iteration 2 :c:
$ IFS="$saveIFS"
```

Comment: Try the following and let me know what you think is happening: IFS='\n'; c=0; for i in $'a\Xnb\nc\n'; do echo iteration $c :$i:; c=$[c+1]; done

Answer (score 0):

Two reasons:

1. Your `for` loop loops only once: there is only one element to loop on, which is the `$'1\n2\n3\n4'` string. If you want to loop four times, you have to change `$IFS`, as suggested by unwind.
2. `echo` takes this string, and interprets it as four arguments separated by newlines. It then displays all arguments separated by whitespaces. If you want that `echo` doesn't interpret the input string, put it in double quotes, as in `echo "$i"`.

Edit, after question edit:

- I tried changing `$IFS`: it worked, but I used `export $IFS='\n'`
- In your second case, `$v` gets interpreted by bash in `for` command which interprets it as four arguments separated by newlines. If you want to get your first problem again, just use `for f in "$v"` instead of `for f in $v`.

Comment: I've extended my question after unsuccessfully trying unwind's suggestion.  I found the for loop does iterate over the same string as long as it is first stored in a variable - without messing with IFS.

Comment: IFS='\n' also works.  What doesn't work is IFS=$'\n'.  I'm very very confused right now.

Comment: I took unwind's and your suggestion to print more details and it turns out IFS='\n' and export IFS='\n' only causes echo to print \n as newlines.  Setting IFS this way did not cause for loop to iterate 4 times.

Comment: Good answer, except for the information about `$IFS`: "If you want to loop four times, you have to change `$IFS`, as suggested by unwind": No: with a _quoted string_ as the loop driver, `$IFS` doesn't come into play.
"it worked, but I used `export $IFS='\n'`": Assuming you meant `export IFS='\n'`: It can't work, as stated; there's no reason to _export_ `IFS`, and `'\n'` assigns _literal_ characters `\ ` and `n`.

Answer (score 0):

try

`c=0; for i in $'1\\n2\\n3\\n4'; do echo -e iteration $c :$i:; c=$[c+1]; done`

the extra backslashes preserve the escapes for the newlines, the `echo -e` tells echo to expand the escapes.

Comment: Sorry.  Didn't work for me.  And it shouldn't work since specification for bash says it won't.

Answer (score 0):

[Dennis Williamson's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1651360/45375) fully explains the symptoms, and even the question itself now mostly does; [mouviciel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1650703/45375) boils the issues down well, but (as of this writing) contains incorrect information about `$IFS`.
  Therefore, let me attempt a **summary of the *rules* that apply**, followed by a detailed analysis:

- With **quoted strings**, irrespective of the quoting style, **[`IFS`, the Internal Field Separator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) *never* comes into play**.

  - **A quoted string as the sole driver of a `for` loop *always* results in a *single* iteration**, with the (potentially expanded) string getting assigned *as a whole* to the loop variable.
- Splitting strings into words by the separator characters specified in **`$IFS`** (*word-splitting*) **only applies to the *results* of *unquoted expansions***, namely:

  - unquoted variable references (`$var`), called *parameter expansions* (which includes transformations such as prefix and suffix removal, substitutions, ...)
  - unquoted command substitutions (`$(...)` or old-style `` `...` ``)
  - unquoted arithmetic expansions (`$(( ... ))` - note that syntax `$[...]` is *obsolete* and should be avoided).
- In order **to assign control characters such as `<newline>` and `<tab>` to `$IFS`**, **use an [ANSI C-quoted string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) (`$'...'`)**, which understands *escape sequences* such as `\n` and `\t`; e.g., `IFS=$'\n'`; by contrast, `IFS='\n'` would assign *2 literal* characters: literal `\` and literal `n` (single-quoted strings always use their content literally).

Note that if the `echo` command in the original code had used a single, double-quoted argument (`echo "iteration $c :$i:"`), then `$IFS` would not have applied altogether, which would have avoided the confusion.

---

#### Analysis of the command from the question:

```
c=0; for i in $'1\n2\n3\n4'; do echo iteration $c :$i:; c=$[c+1]; done
```

- `$IFS` and word-splitting *only* apply to the `echo` command, not the `for` loop.
- ANSI C-quoted string `$'1\n2\n3\n4'` as the loop driver results in the following 4-line string assigned to `$i`:

  ```
  1
  2
  3
  4
  ```
- `echo iteration $c :$i:`, due to having only *unquoted* arguments, makes the shell subject them to *word-splitting* as well as *globbing* (*filename expansion*; although that has no effect in this particular case):

  - `$c`, due to containing just `0` (in the one and only iteration) is not modified in the process.
  - `:$i:`, by contrast, based on `$IFS` containing `<space><tab><newline>` by default, is split into *4 separate words*: `:1`, `2`, `3`, and `4:` - note how the enclosing `:` became part of the first and last word.
  - Note: To **use a variable's value as-is, always double-quote** the variable reference.
    Word splitting and globbing are instances of *[shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)*, which is the umbrella term for the up-front interpretation of arguments by the shell.
- `echo` is therefore handed *6 individual arguments*: `iteration`, `0`, and `:1`, `2`, `3`, and `4:`. On *output*, `echo` concatenates its arguments with a *single space* (unrelated to `$IFS`), yielding `iteration 0 :1 2 3 4:`

---

#### How to write the loop robustly

Note the double-quoting of the string passed to `echo`, and the embedded arithmetic expansion that combines reporting the current value of `$c` with incrementing it afterwards (`$((c++))`).

**If the iteration values are known in advance:**

```
# Simply use an unquoted, space-separated list (the indiv. elements may be quoted, however).
c=0; for i in 1 2 3 4; do echo "iteration: $((c++)) :$i:"; done

# Alternative, with an array:
vals=( 1 2 3 4 )
c=0; for i in "${vals[@]}"; do echo "iteration: $((c++)) :$i:"; done

# If the iteration values form a range of numbers, you can also use
# brace expansion (`for i in {1..4}...`) or, better for larger ranges
# and required for variable-based endpoints, a C-style loop (`for ((i=0;i<4;++i))...`)
```

**If the iteration values are NOT known in advance:**

Using [`for` to loop over lines of input is ill-advised](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), because the use of an unquoted expansion would require you to deal with possibly unwanted word-splitting and globbing, and because the entire input must be read into memory as a whole before the loop starts.

A `while` loop to which the lines are provided via stdin is the better choice (`<<<` is a [here-string](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument?action=show&redirect=HereString), a string that is passed via stdin):

```
c=0; while IFS= read -r i; do echo "iteration: $((c++)) :$i:"; done <<<$'1\n2\n3\n4'
```

`read` reads line by line, and `-r` combined with `IFS=` (disabling word-splitting by setting it to the null string) ensures that each line is read in full, as-is.
Note that by prepending `IFS=`  directly to `read`, its value is *localized to that command*, without changing the current shell's `$IFS` value - this is a [generic mechanism in POSIX-compatible shells](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01).